# How to set the range of stats function in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a time series of data as shown below and I would like to plot all the data, the mean value for a specific range, e.g. 3, 6, or 9 months.

```
    Time           T      D      T/D
    8/1/2021    1785.28 23.99   74.42
    7/1/2021    1807.84 25.68   70.40
    6/1/2021    1834.57 27  67.95
    5/1/2021    1850.26 27.5    67.28
    4/1/2021    1760.04 25.69   68.51
    3/1/2021    1718.23 25.65   66.99
    2/1/2021    1808.17 27.29   66.26
    1/1/2021    1866.98 25.88   72.14
    12/1/2020   1858.42 24.97   74.43
    11/1/2020   1866.3  24.08   77.50
    10/1/2020   1900.27 24.23   78.43
    9/1/2020    1921.92 25.74   74.67
    8/1/2020    1968.63 27  72.91
```

I am using gnuplot 5.2 and I tried to plot using the following code but it seems that the stats did not work as I expected.

```
  # plot data vs date 
    
    reset session
    
    FILE = "data_01.dat"

    set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y"
    stats ["8/1/2020":"1/1/2021"] FILE u 4 name "A"
    stats ["8/1/2020":"8/1/2021"] FILE u 4 name "B"

    set label 1  sprintf("6 months average= %.2f",A_mean) at graph 0.02, graph 0.95
    set label 2  sprintf("12 months average= %.2f",B_mean) at graph 0.02, graph 0.90

    set xdata time
    set format x "%m/%y"
    set xrange ["8/1/2020":"8/1/2021"]
    
    plot FILE u 1:4 skip 1 w lp lc rgb 'blue' t 'data' ,\
    A_mean lc rgb 'black' t '6 months avg',\
    B_mean lc rgb 'red' t '12 months avg'
    
  # end of code
```

the output that I get is like this:
[data_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jveLr.png)

I think I made a mistake in setting the limit of stats which make the stats calculate the mean for the whole data in the column instead of calculates it within a specific range. But I could not find how to fix it. At first I tried using this one

```
stats ["8/1/2020":"1/1/2021"] FILE u (timecolumn(1)):4 name "A"
```

but it did not give me any output and ended with: "undefined variable: A_mean".
How can I properly set the range of stats function in gnuplot?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a small error in the `using` part of your `stats` command, it should say `using 1:4` – otherwise the row number is used as x. In my understanding, `set xdata time` should go before `stats`. However, this raises the error "Stats command not available in timedata mode", so it seems to me that a solution is not straightforward…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Eldrad already mentioned all the essentials... when I was still coding...

`stats` does not work with timedata, i.e. `set xdata time`.
Furthermore, if you want to limit by the first date column you have to use column 1 in `stats` as well.
Check the modified code which will give a reasonable result.

**Edit:**
instead of using `strptime(myTimeFmt,"8/1/2020")` many times you can also define a function `myTime(s) = strptime(myTimeFmt,s)` which shortens everything a bit and doesn't let it look that "scary".

**Code:**

```
# plot data vs date and using stats 
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Time           T      D      T/D
8/1/2021    1785.28 23.99   74.42
7/1/2021    1807.84 25.68   70.40
6/1/2021    1834.57 27  67.95
5/1/2021    1850.26 27.5    67.28
4/1/2021    1760.04 25.69   68.51
3/1/2021    1718.23 25.65   66.99
2/1/2021    1808.17 27.29   66.26
1/1/2021    1866.98 25.88   72.14
12/1/2020   1858.42 24.97   74.43
11/1/2020   1866.3  24.08   77.50
10/1/2020   1900.27 24.23   78.43
9/1/2020    1921.92 25.74   74.67
8/1/2020    1968.63 27  72.91
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%m/%d/%Y"
set timefmt myTimeFmt
myTime(s) = strptime(myTimeFmt,s)

stats [myTime("8/1/2020"):myTime("1/1/2021")] $Data u (timecolumn(1)):4 name "A" nooutput
stats [myTime("8/1/2020"):myTime("8/1/2021")] $Data u (timecolumn(1)):4 name "B" nooutput

set label 1  sprintf("6 months average= %.2f",A_mean_y) at graph 0.02, graph 0.95
set label 2  sprintf("12 months average= %.2f",B_mean_y) at graph 0.02, graph 0.90

set format x "%m/%y" time
set xrange [myTime("8/1/2020"):myTime("8/1/2021")]

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1)):4 skip 1 w lp lc rgb 'blue' t 'data' ,\
     A_mean_y lc rgb 'black' t '6 months avg',\
     B_mean_y lc rgb 'red'   t '12 months avg'
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @theozh, your code give me a better understanding of how to limit the `stats` with this type of data. I thought the set `timefmt` makes column 1 can be directly used to limit the range as in the `set xrange` in my code which works fine for the plot but not for the `stats`.

Comment: @Agung You're welcome. To my understanding, if you write `using 4` in the `stats' command it will try to limit your column 4 within your time limits, which doesn't match.

Comment: @theozh Ah, that's definitely a more straight-forward or "cleaner" solution than my approach, I was struggling with all these time functions… Anyway, `using 4` in `stats` is interpreted just as in `plot`, i.e. the line number is taken as x (which ofc doesn't match the time range). Or in other words, it is a synonym for `using 0:4`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using timedata inside `stats` is not implemented in gnuplot, at least in version 5.5. I found an (ugly) workaround based on [gnuplot: xdata time & calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922381/gnuplot-xdata-time-calculations) that transforms the input time and the range definitions into seconds from 1.1.1970, compares whether the input value is larger than the lower bound and smaller than the upper bound; if yes, returns the actual y value, if not, returns NaN, which is then ignored by `stats`.

```
reset session
fmt="%m/%d/%Y"      #shortcut for the format string

FILE = "data_01.dat"
stats FILE u 1:(strptime(fmt,stringcolumn(1)) >= strptime(fmt,"8/1/2020") && strptime(fmt,stringcolumn(1)) <= strptime(fmt,"1/1/2021") ? $4 : NaN) name "A"
```

Explanation of the functions: `strptime` transforms a time string (the second argument), which is formatted according to the first argument, into UNIX time. Hence, the x value, which is read from the file, needs to be handled as a string. `$1` would provide a number, not a string, therefore `stringcolumn` has to be used instead. In this way, you get the mean value of the y column, which is stored as `A_mean_y` (note the '_y'!).

But maybe someone has a more elegant solution than me…

Comment: Thanks, @Eldrad! I understand that the `stats` does not work with timedata, that is why I put the `set xdata time` after the `stats`. But I did not realize that I need to use the strptime  in the `stats` to use it with the `stringcolumn`.  Thank you for your clear explanation including the A_mean_y!